# Adding required asteriks to label in Angular 7

Tags: css

I'm using angular 7. And I want a label with **red** required asteriks when label has `required` attribute. I wrote `app.component.css` like below Stackblitz. But it didn't worked. **What can be the reason of not working? (Or another way of doing this job?)**

app.component.css

```
label.required::after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<label required>Test Content</label>
```

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1ccce)

I want to show result as

`Test Content *`

Comment: You mean like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u32thr

Comment: Thanks @Vega. `label[required]::after {content: " *"; color: red;}` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label.required` is a selector for a label with the **class** `required`.

```
<label class="required">
```

For a label with an **attribute** `required`, it would be `label[required]`.

That is pure CSS, BTW, and has absolutely nothing to do with Angular and TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks , it worked. @JBNizet. You're right. I firstly think solve this by `directive` . But , this is better way. I will change the `angular` keyword.